# VK API, как обратиться к id определённых постов в группе?

Tags: python, json, парсер, vkontakte-api

метод wall.get, Python

```
def Response():
    response = requests.get("https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get", params = {'access_token':token, 'v': version,"domain":"domain","count":"99"}) 
    response = response.json()['response']['items'] 
    for k in range (len(response)):
        result = print(str(int((response[k]["id"]))))
    return result

Response()
```

но здесь получается non-type объект, с которым я работать не могу, а я например хочу вывести id постов, которые >= 48000 (например)/ При этом результат в консоль выводит с 99 запрошенными id.

Это возможно сделать? PS: поменять/поставить точный count здесь не вариант, опция не подойдёт в данном случае + я хочу эти id переносить в wall post дальше. Поэтому нужно разобраться как правильно обратиться к ним.

Comment: Осознал, что можно искусственно вписывать кодом промежуток постов в wall-post сразу указывая первый и последний, ну и дальше по инструкции, так как они идут по порядку в принципе. Но тогда зачем нужен wall get? Просто для парсинга? Никак данные не перетащить в другой метод? P.S - создавать CVS file и потом через pandas в голову только пришло

Comment: Еще осознайте, что вопрос нужно оформлять нормально, чтобы ваш код читался так, как поожено.